# Azure Data Factory- How to feed data into a foreach activity from setvariable activity which hold values from a lookup table?

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I have below lookup table which returns below table list.

```
{
  "count": 2,
  "value" : [
      {
      "NAME": "table1"
},
{"NAME": "table2"}
]
}
```

now i want to keep the table name value into a setvariable, so that i can pass these value into a foreach.

i set the expression in setvariable activity

```
@activity('myLookupActivityName').output.value"
```

and in foreach, i set below expression

```
@variables('MyVariableName')
```

below is the output of set variable

```
{
  "value": {
    "table_name_list": [
      {
        "NAME": "table1"
      },
      {
        "NAME": "table2"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

But foreach taking nothing from the array list.

i dont want table names to be passed directly from lookup table into foreach.

So how can fetch each table name from the setvaraible and pass into foreach?

Comment: what error you are getting from above process? what is your expected result?

Comment: Hi Rakesh
It return nothing to the foreach

Comment: Can you show your pipeline flow? and what is your expected result here? Do you want to pass the lookup output array to ForEach using a set variable right?

Comment: "Do you want to pass the lookup output array to ForEach using a set variable right? " - Yes.. sorry i cannot share as it in secured and restricted place.. i just added output from setvariable

Comment: 'But foreach taking nothing from the array list' - @variables('<variable_name>') should work for the foreach. Can you provide the foreach input and output JSON?

Comment: If you passed `@activity('myLookupActivityName').output.value` to the set variable activity output should be like this https://i.imgur.com/gDLkph3.png.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your set variable activity should not be like above. Follow the below step-by-step process to achieve your requirement.

First give your file to lookup activity and uncheck the **FirstRow** in it. Then make sure the **created variable is an array type**.

[image]

In the set variable activity give the expression `@activity('Lookup1').output.value` for the `tables_list` variable.

It will give the output like below.

```
{
    "name": "table_list",
    "value": [
        {
            "NAME": "table1"
        },
        {
            "NAME": "table2"
        }
    ]
}
```

[image]

Then, give the `@variables('tables_list')` expression to the For-Each activity and use your activities inside it.

[image]

Here, for sample I have assigned `@item().name` to string variable inside for-loop and you can see its working as expected.

[image]

**Use the below pipeline JSON to build your pipeline:**

```
{
    "name": "pipeline1",
    "properties": {
        "activities": [
            {
                "name": "Lookup1",
                "type": "Lookup",
                "dependsOn": [],
                "policy": {
                    "timeout": "0.12:00:00",
                    "retry": 0,
                    "retryIntervalInSeconds": 30,
                    "secureOutput": false,
                    "secureInput": false
                },
                "userProperties": [],
                "typeProperties": {
                    "source": {
                        "type": "DelimitedTextSource",
                        "storeSettings": {
                            "type": "AzureBlobFSReadSettings",
                            "recursive": true,
                            "enablePartitionDiscovery": false
                        },
                        "formatSettings": {
                            "type": "DelimitedTextReadSettings"
                        }
                    },
                    "dataset": {
                        "referenceName": "source_csv",
                        "type": "DatasetReference"
                    },
                    "firstRowOnly": false
                }
            },
            {
                "name": "Set variable1",
                "type": "SetVariable",
                "dependsOn": [
                    {
                        "activity": "Lookup1",
                        "dependencyConditions": [
                            "Succeeded"
                        ]
                    }
                ],
                "policy": {
                    "secureOutput": false,
                    "secureInput": false
                },
                "userProperties": [],
                "typeProperties": {
                    "variableName": "table_list",
                    "value": {
                        "value": "@activity('Lookup1').output.value",
                        "type": "Expression"
                    }
                }
            },
            {
                "name": "ForEach1",
                "type": "ForEach",
                "dependsOn": [
                    {
                        "activity": "Set variable1",
                        "dependencyConditions": [
                            "Succeeded"
                        ]
                    }
                ],
                "userProperties": [],
                "typeProperties": {
                    "items": {
                        "value": "@variables('table_list')",
                        "type": "Expression"
                    },
                    "isSequential": true,
                    "activities": [
                        {
                            "name": "Set variable2",
                            "type": "SetVariable",
                            "dependsOn": [],
                            "policy": {
                                "secureOutput": false,
                                "secureInput": false
                            },
                            "userProperties": [],
                            "typeProperties": {
                                "variableName": "name",
                                "value": {
                                    "value": "@item().name",
                                    "type": "Expression"
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                }
            }
        ],
        "variables": {
            "table_list": {
                "type": "Array"
            },
            "name": {
                "type": "String"
            }
        },
        "annotations": []
    }
}
```